# Design for assingning output with the counted value of clock on some condition in VHDL

Tags: counter, vhdl, clock

I'm new to VHDL and confused with this design

when Acknwledgement= '1' and clk='1' then

count should be count+1;

and when Acknwledgement= '0' my total counted value of clocks should be assigned to the 'output'  and after that resetting count='0' and output='0'.

can anyone help with this.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Code from comment pasted in:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
entity acknw is
    port (acknw  : in  std_logic;
          clk    : in  std_logic;
          output : out integer range 0 to 15);
end acknw;
architecture Behavioral of acknw is
begin
    process(clk, acknw) variable c : integer range 0 to 15;
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk = '1') then
            if(acknw = '1') then 
                 c := c+1;
                 output <= c;
            else 
                 c := 0;
                 output <= c;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I worked out something like this
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity acknw is
Port ( acknw: in STD_LOGIC;
clk : in STD_LOGIC;
output : out INTEGER RANGE 0 To 15);
end acknw;

architecture Behavioral of acknw is
begin
process(clk,acknw)
variable c : INTEGER RANGE 0 To 15 ;
begin

if(clk'event and clk='1') then
if(acknw='1') then

c := c+1;
output <= c;
else
c := 0 ;
output <= c;
end if; 
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;

Instead of making my process to work on clock condition , it should work on the acknw condition and then checking my clock condition. can anyone guide me !!!

Comment: When you say 'it should work on the acnkw condition' do you mean that it should only do something on an edge of acknw? As a separate note acknw does not need to appear in the sensitivity list of your process as it is a clocked process. You would only need it there if you used it as an asynchronous event, like for example an asynchronous reset.

Comment: yes it should only do something on an edge of acknw.And something like an asynchronous reseti.e., when my acknw =1 and my clk=1 then it should count and when my acknw='0' my counted value should be the output like for example ouput is 126,32(counts of clk).

Answer (score 0):

from your comment it sounds like you want an asynchronous acknw, try something like this:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
entity acknw is
    port (acknw  : in  std_logic;
          clk    : in  std_logic;
          output : out integer range 0 to 15);
end acknw;
architecture Behavioral of acknw is
begin
    process(clk, acknw) 
    begin
        if (acknw = '0') then
          output <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
          -- rollover
          if (output /= 15) then
            output <= output + 1;
          else
            output <= 0;
          end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```